# dropdownlist in partial view not expanding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-select

I am developing an asp.net MVC4 web app where I need to show StateList and CountryList. I am having a dropdownlist for Countries and on changing i am getting a partial view to display the corresponding States through an ajax request. The partial view has the dropdownlist for States. But once rendered, the dropdownlist for States is not expanding. Here is the code.

**First View:**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 12%">
           <div class="col-md-12 control-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="margin-top :1%;"><b>Country:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.SelectedCountryId, Model.CountryList, New With {.style = "width:100px", .type = "text", .id = "country"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.SelectedCountryId)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="stateDiv"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var rootUrl = $('#rootUrl').val();

    $('#country').change(function () {
        var countryCode = $(this).val();
        $.get(rootUrl + 'GetStateList', { countryCodeId: countryCode }, function (data) {
            $('#stateDiv').html(data);
        }, 'html');

        var isUSCAN = false;
        if ($(this).val() == 1 || $(this).val() == 2) {
            isUSCAN = true;
        }
        $('#stateSelect').toggle(isUSCAN);
        $('#stateText').toggle(!isUSCAN);

        var isCAN = $(this).val() == 2;
        $('#provinceLabel').toggle(isCAN);
        $('#stateLabel').toggle(!isCAN);

    }).change();
});
```

**Controller:**

```
Function GetStateList(countryCodeId As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return PartialView("PartialStateList", Defendant)
End Function
```

**PartialStateList View**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 12%">
           <div class="col-md-12 control-group">
                    <label id="stateLabel" class="col-md-4 control-label" style="margin-top :1%;"><b>State:</b></label>
                    <label id="provinceLabel" class="col-md-4 control-label" style="margin-top :1%;"><b>Province:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.SelectedStateId, Model.StateList, New With {.style = "width:100px", .type = "text", .id = "stateSelect"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.SelectedStateId, New With {.style = "width:100px", .value = "", .type = "text", .id = "stateText"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.SelectedStateId)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The html that is rendered when i check in browser has the entire list of states, but when i click on the dropdownlist, it is not expanding and showing the list. Please let me know if there is something I am missing.

Comment: Are there actually items in the list? Also, make sure there aren't any javascript errors.

Comment: there are items on the list and no javascript errors. i pulled the script into 2 files one for the first view and one for the partiallistview and it is working. Thanks